# Raw Excel Data contains different Date formats

Tags: matlab, vba, date, excel

I have huge amounts of raw data that are separated by columns. All is well when i import these to Matlab except for the fact that I just saw that the excel files contains different formats for the dates.

One series (i.e 3 days, 1 row or each hour gets 3x24 rows) have its' dates in the format "mm/dd/yyyy" which neither excel or matlab recognizes as proper dates.

I've tried solving this problem in different ways. First i tried to just highlight the cells and use the function `format cells`, but this didn't work since excel doesn't see them as 'cells' but rather as 'text'.

Then i tried the `Text to columns` function which didn't work either (delimited or fixed width).

Im really stuck and would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: could you please add to the question some examples of every case that you have so we can help?

Comment: When you used text-to-columns, did you also select the date format as being MDY?  And did you ensure that no parts were being split out into separate columns?  That should be the simplest method of handling the problem, unless the "/" is not really a "/", or there are some other non-ASCII characters in the string.  What is the source of the information?

Comment: Yes sorry, here's an example sheet:

http://www.filedropper.com/testheat97

At the moment my concern is to importing it to matlab and then converting the dates so that they're all relevant and the same for comparison later on.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel:

If cell `A1` has a string like `mm/dd/yyyy` then try this:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4), LEFT(A1,2), MID(A1,4,2))
```

In Matlab:

```
=datenum(yourDateString, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Interesting.

My column looks like this atm;

10/21/2014
10/21/2014
10/21/2014
10/20/14
10/20/14
10/20/14
10/19/14

as you can see, some of them become in a weird format. I would like for all of them to be in the "dd/mm/yy" format but when i use the datenum command matlab translate it to a number, which I guess isn't that bad either.

Comment: @Emil call `datestr` after then to convert it back to a string in the format that you like

Answer (score 0):

Select the desired range to fix and use this script:

```
Sub bulk_Date_fix()
    on error resume next
    Set d_ranged = Selection
    For Each a In d_ranged
        a.Value = Split(a.Value, "/")(0) & "/" & Split(a.Value, "/")(1) & "/" & Split(a.Value, "/")(2)
    Next
    on error goto 0
End Sub
```

How it works: The above script loops through all the cells in the selected area and splits out the various attributes of a date based on the "/" symbol.

Comment: Thanks Mike!

I created a button with ur script which seemed to work the first time i pressed it but then i accedently pressed it again and it reverted back to the original formats. Also It doesnt work after that.

I realized now that Im sitting here that It's gonna be to tough handling all this data in just excel so think im gonna try to focus on a matlab solution. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: Your welcome. It's odd that it reverts back ... I ran this script over the same selected area several times and the fix stayed fixed. If you want to send me your spreadsheet, I can look at it to why it changes after the first run.

Answer (score 0):

I examined your file and you will need to go back to the source data to straighten this out.  Instead of "opening" the file in Excel, you will need to IMPORT the file.  When you do that, the text import wizard will open, and you can then designate the date column as being of the format DMY (or whatever format is being generated by the source).

The problem is that there is a mismatch between the format of the file, and your Windows Regional Short date format.  If you look at Row 229, you will see that real dates are present, but out of sequence with the rest.

Excel parses dates being input according to the Windows Regional Short Date settings. If the date doesn't make sense, according to that parsing (e.g. month > 12) , Excel will interpret the date as a string; if the date does make sense, it will be interpreted as a date in accordance with that windows regional date component order, and this will be different from what is intended.

So the first few hundred dates are strings, but at line 229, the date, which is probably meant to be 12 OCT 2014, gets changed to 10 DEC 2014.  This will happen in other areas where that value in the 2nd position is 12 or less.

**EDIT:** I am not certain of the variabilities inherent in using XL on the MAC. In the Windows version of XL, the "text import" feature is on the Data Ribbon / Get External Data Tab:

[image: Data Ribbon]

When you click on that and open a text file, you will see the Text Import Wizard, and when you get to Step 3, you will be able to specify the text format of the data to be imported:

[image: Text Import Wizard Step 3]

Comment: Import to matlab? I tried doing that but matlab gets the same problem. Also Im on a Mac so not really sure what the Windows Regional Short date format is and how it affects me here, but maybe Im just not thinking it through.

Comment: @Emil No, as I wrote, IMPORT to Excel.  I'll edit my answer to show you where.  I don't know how to set the equivalent of the Windows short date format on a Mac.